# Checkbox and radiobutton won't show

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on a html theme and want to add my form, I've been messing with the css but that didn't work. The checkboxes and radiobutton aren't visible. Here's the link for the form. http://watisklantenmailen.nl/test/formulier.php
Hope someone can help out. Thanks!

Comment: '_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._'

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Describe the exact problem, provide the code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry, next time I'll make my question a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `opacity: 0` for checkboxes and radio buttons in `main.css`. Remove it and they will appear in your page.

`opacity` sets the transparency of an element. Therefore `opacity: 1` means no transparency while `opacity: 0` means element having full transparency (invisible on the page).

```
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -2em;
  opacity: 0;  // <<==== Remove this property to make checkboxes appear.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your css file
I found that in main.css file you have the following rule
`input[type="checkbox"],
    input[type="radio"] {
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -ms-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin-right: -2em;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 1em;
        z-index: -1;
    }`
you should remove the opacity: 0; to see your checkboxes